# Team Foundation Server - Backdate Epics

Tags: tfs, backlog

I am taking over a catalog of projects that already initiated. My job is to enter the projects into TFS and use the 'work' features. I am entering each project as an Epic...15 Epics total.  When I enter an Epic is used the date I enter it as the project initiation day.  Is there a way to grandfather in Epics in TFS.  Adding Epics with a start date in the past?  I cannot congigure the cumulative flow diagram properly without being able to back date entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Epics, the default field "CreateDate" can't be changed. It uses the date and time when the Epic created.

As a alternative, you can customize a field to use DateTimeControl, then you can select Date and change the time in this custom field:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to change the create date from TFS Web Portal. But if you create the work item via [TFS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet), you can enable the **bypassrule** which allow you specify the create date of the work item. Following is a code sample for this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://collectionurl/";
        TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url));
        WorkItemStore wis = new WorkItemStore(ttpc.Name,WorkItemStoreFlags.BypassRules);
        Project pro = wis.Projects["ProjectName"];
        WorkItemTypeCollection wits = pro.WorkItemTypes;
        WorkItem wi = new WorkItem(wits["Epic"]);
        wi.Fields["System.Title"].Value = "Title";
        wi.Fields["System.CreatedDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-09-01");
        wi.Save();
    }
```

Note: To use this, you must be the member of "Project Collection Administrators" security group.

Refer to this link for details: [TFS API Part 48 – WorkItemControl And Bypass Work Item Rules](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/02/20/tfs-api-part-48-workitemcontrol-and-bypass-work-item-rules/).